# redirect, can't leave login page

Tags: django, redirect

having trouble with this tutorial. in my views.py I have this function for login, in views.py:

```
def login_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    form = AuthenticationForm(request, data=request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        user_ = form.get_user()
        login(request, user_)
        **return redirect("/")**
    context = {
        "form": form,
        "btn_label": "Login",
        "title": "Login"
    }
    return render(request, "accounts/auth.html", context)
```

however when i try to change the redirect , i only get errors, what should I put in the redirect? i've tried everything like

```
return redirect("/tweets/list.html")
```

and

```
 return redirect("public/index.html")
```

both are locations of file names in the templates folder. I am getting the error, "Page not found (404)". The only address that did redirect was when I put https://www.google.com/

in accounts/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth import login, logout, authenticate
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm, UserCreationForm
# Create your views here.

# Function based views to Class Based Views

def login_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    form = AuthenticationForm(request, data=request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        user_ = form.get_user()
        login(request, user_)
        return redirect('')
    context = {
        "form": form,
        "btn_label": "Login",
        "title": "Login"
    }
    return render(request, "accounts/auth.html", context)

def logout_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    if request.method == "POST":
        logout(request)
        return redirect("/login")
    context = {
        "form": None,
        "description": "Are you sure you want to logout?",
        "btn_label": "Click to Confirm",
        "title": "Logout"
    }
    return render(request, "accounts/auth.html", context)


def register_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    form = UserCreationForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        user = form.save(commit=True)
        user.set_password(form.cleaned_data.get("password1"))
        # send a confirmation email to verify their account
        login(request, user)
        return redirect("/")
    context = {
        "form": form,
        "btn_label": "Register",
        "title": "Register"
    }
    return render(request, "accounts/auth.html", context)
```

here is urls.py:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, re_path, include # url()
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

from accounts.views import (
    login_view,
    logout_view,
    register_view,
)

from tweets.views import (
    home_view,
    tweets_list_view,
    tweets_detail_view,
)

urlpatterns = [
    path('', home_view),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('global/', tweets_list_view),
    path('login/', login_view),
    path('logout/', logout_view),
    path('register/', register_view),
    path('<int:tweet_id>', tweets_detail_view),
    re_path(r'profiles?/', include('profiles.urls')),
    path('api/tweets/', include('tweets.api.urls')),
    re_path(r'api/profiles?/', include('profiles.api.urls')),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, 
                document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

thnx

Comment: You should go through the [**`redirect(...)`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect) doc to understand what all things can be a ***valid input*** for the function.

Comment: you do not redirect on template but on view, if you have templates that need to be hosted directly, host them using  nginix/apache config or create an url/views entry for them

Comment: insert the name of the url, easy

Comment: but I want it to be redirected to tweet list or profile page, not to some external url

Comment: @iklinac the redirect is in views.py

Answer (score 0):

Redirect should take a valid path to an `url` defined in `urls.Py`, not a file in `templates/some/urls.html`.

I would suggest not to used "hard coded urls" though, but instead using the view name and parameters such as `return redirect('some-view-name', foo='bar')`

Comment: i put: return redirect('tweets_list_view') wherein 'tweets_list_view' is a view in my urls.py, but now i get an error: NoReverseMatch at /login/
Reverse for 'tweets_list_view' not found. 'tweets_list_view' is not a valid view function or pattern name. With parameters, do you mean the parameters passed into the function 'tweets_list_view' like request, *args, **kwargs? thnx

Comment: what do you mean "is a view defined in urls.py" ? Can you give the urls block from urls.py ?

Comment: i posted the views.py and urls.py above - i meant 'tweets_list_view' is a view imported into my urls.py -thnx

Comment: `return redirect("/login")` misses a trailing "/".

Answer (score 0):

i solved the error by looking at urls.py, looking into url patterns, picking

```
path('global/', tweets_list_view),
```

and dropping '/global/' into return redirect("/") so that line looks like:

return redirect("/global/")